# Executing command-line calls inside a Docker container from Java

Tags: java, docker, process, quarkus, processbuilder

I'm currently working on a microservice using the Quarkus framework for Java. Quarkus allows directly building a container which runs the application in JVM mode using Maven. This works very well, I can start the container and then query the exposed port from my host machine. The image is based on the ubi-minimal image provided by RedHat.

For data processing I need a utility called tabix which is included in a package called [htslib](https://github.com/samtools/htslib). My first hunch was to install this inside of the container so whatever machine starts the container does not need to have tabix/htslib installed:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.3 

ARG JAVA_PACKAGE=java-11-openjdk-headless
ARG RUN_JAVA_VERSION=1.3.8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# Install java and the run-java script
# Also set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN microdnf install curl ca-certificates ${JAVA_PACKAGE} make tar gcc bzip2 \
    && microdnf update \
    && microdnf clean all \
    && mkdir /deployments \
    && chown 1001 /deployments \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /deployments \
    && chown 1001:root /deployments \
    && curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && chown 1001 /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && echo "securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom" >> /etc/alternatives/jre/conf/security/java.security

# Configure the JAVA_OPTIONS, you can add -XshowSettings:vm to also display the heap size.
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=1001 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=1001 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=1001 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=1001 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

# Set up HTSLib
RUN mkdir /package \
    && chown 1001 /package \
    && chmod g+rwX /package \
    && chown 1001:root /package \
    && curl -LJ https://github.com/samtools/htslib/releases/download/1.12/htslib-1.12.tar.bz2 -o /package/htslib.zip \
    && tar xjvf /package/htslib.zip \
    && ls -l

# Install HTSLib
WORKDIR /htslib-1.12/
RUN microdnf install zlib-devel bzip2-devel xz-devel \
    && microdnf update \
    && ./configure
RUN make \
    && make install

EXPOSE 8085
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

This seems to work, at least I can call `tabix` when I shell into the container. However, the problem is that now I want to call it directly from the Java code. I tried using a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
String[] command = new String[] {
            "tabix",
            FILEPATH+filename
        };
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        try {
            final Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while creating tabix index file");
        }
```

What I want the method here to do is to create an indexing file (`.tbi`) from a variant call format file that I mount into the container. This works on my machine, which has tabix installed. However, when I try doing this on another machine, it does not work and delivers no output even though I'm using the exact same container image and files. This is why I suspect that the ProcessBuilder is actually calling `tabix` on the host machine instead of inside the docker container, which seems pretty weird/unsafe to me, but I'm struggling to come up with another explanation.
In any case, I would appreciate any help on how to execute the process inside the container, if that is at all possible, or any other advice.
Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual exception?  The overall approach you have (building the support tool into the same image) seems right; a container can't run binaries on the host or another container.  It also could be interesting to see how you're launching the container, and how you've manually verified that the support binary works.

Comment: @DavidMaze Hey, thank you for your answer! There is no real exception per se, sadly. I launch the container the same way on both machines: `docker run --rm -p 8085:8085 -v /path/to/files/:/mnt <container:tag>`. I then send a GET query to the endpoint with cURL - On my home machine, this prompts the container to create the tbi file (which takes a few minutes), process the data and then output some JSON. However, on a different machine, it instantly returns empty JSON and does not create the file in the first place.

Comment: As for the verification, I tried to do that by calling `docker exec -it <container> bash` and calling `tabix` from there, which on both machines returns man page content for tabix (since I did not give any additional input), so I think it works. I'm not 100% sure though because this is the first time I'm having to install a utility like this inside a container and also the first time I'm working with a RedHat image.

Comment: Does the `Exception occurred ...` message appear on the container logs?  Can you tell if the subprocess is starting, and if so, if it printed out any diagnostics?  (For example, there are lots of SO questions around permissions of bind-mounted directories, and if the subprocess can't read the input file it might exit immediately.)

Comment: Looking into the logs helped - It seemed to be a combination of permission issues and of the file in question not being in the right format for tabix. For some reason, on my PC it is tabix-compliant but on my institute's machine it isnt. I will have to look into why that is, but at least I'm glad the issue isnt primarily docker-related. Thank you!